# DynamicExpressionParser not working while concating two arrays

Tags: c#, dynamic-expression

I want to concat two array in LINQ dynamic parser.

I am sending dictionary input as below

```
    object a= new object[]{1d,0d,1d};
    object b = new object[]{};
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dict["KIStrike"] = a;
    dict["NonKIStrike"] = b;
```

It throws **{"')' or ',' expected"}** exception, when I am executing below statement

```
var exp = "Enumerable.Concat(dict[\"KIStrike\"] as IEnumerable<object>, dict[\"NonKIStrike\"] as IEnumerable<object>)";
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), "dict");
var lambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { param }, null, exp);
var result = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(dict);
```

Whether my expression is incorrect. Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks in advance!!!.

Comment: Does it fail during compile time? Should you escape quotes in exp?

Comment: Compile time there are no issue. actually I entered this text manually that's why its coming let me update

Comment: Also I checked array docs and looks like it does not implement generic interfaces: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0.

Comment: If I execute below statement in LinqPad it works correctly Enumerable.Concat(dict["KIStrike"] as IEnumerable<object>, dict["NonKIStrike"] as IEnumerable<object>)

Comment: is there any other way to append array in linq parser, I will try that

Comment: it seems casting doesn't work in DynamicExpressions. e.g. "(dict[\"KIStrike\"] as IEnumerable) " is also giving same exception

Comment: Hey, I checked the sources of the dynamic linq and I very doubt it supports what you are trying to do - cast value. Its syntaxis is documented [here](https://dynamic-linq.net/expression-language) and it is very limited. I think we might hit [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - trying to make dynamic query work for the solution which does not require dynamic query. Please elaborate in your question what are you trying to achieve, what forces you to use dynamic LINQ.

Comment: Hi fenexil, the solution seems to be really complicated.I dont want to implement that, I found the alternate way. I am not doing concatination using dynamic expressions, but I am doing it later in XSLT file where I will actually need it. Thanks for your time!!!